# Use proxy or Tor within Heroku rails app to hide IP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, tor

I'm using Mechanize inside a rake task that is run by a scheduler add-on to my ruby app on Heroku.  In the script, I am logging into a webpage which worked until recently when the script could no longer log-in.  When I began debugging, Mechanize shows different form fields when I run the script in the heroku console than on my local console.

**Local ruby console** shows these fields:

```
>> asf.fields.each do |f| puts f.name end
__VIEWSTATE
__PREVIOUSPAGE
__EVENTVALIDATION
login$field
password$field
```

**Heroku console** shows one additional field that does NOT appear in the html source:

```
>> asf.fields.each do |f| puts f.name end
__VIEWSTATE 
__PREVIOUSPAGE
__EVENTVALIDATION
login$field
password$field
captcha$txtCaptcha
```

When I issue:

```
>> asf.click_button
```

**Update:**
I tried changing the user agent to several different browser aliases with no luck.  It appears that the IP address from Heroku is causing the captcha to be served up.  Would it be possible to make a request through a proxy server or use Tor to keep the IP from being exposed?

Comment: They might be serving up the captcha just for clients connecting from your IP or Heroku's IP range (perhaps because of your rake task). You might be able to confirm this by checking the output of curl. Aside from that, maybe check that your local Mechanize is the same version as the one on Heroku, or experiment with changing the user agent string.

Comment: local user_agent = Mechanize/2.1 Ruby/1.8.7p249  heroku user_agent =Mechanize/2.1 Ruby/1.9.2p180.  Would the differing ruby versions affect it as well?

Comment: try to load cookies from your local machine into mechanize and change user_agent to normal

Comment: I've tried several user_agent aliases but it doesn't affect anything.  What do you mean change the user_agent to 'normal'?

Comment: sounds like an IP issue to me

Comment: what site are you trying to hack into that requires a password?

Comment: @MatthewFord: can't answer that one. Its a site I log into regularly for work.  I need to automate logins to reduce repetitive tasks required to check pertinent changes I need to be aware of.

Comment: :) will have to trust you on that one then. But yes, setting up a bunch of tor proxies is non trivial

Comment: "worked until recently when the script could no longer log-in" - sounds like the Network Admin is on to you ;). If so & a Heroku IP address is causing a bot defense (captcha) to be served, then a Tor exit node is almost certain to have the same effect. Suggest a proxy is better way to go - or, if it is for your work, you could ask them to white-list your IP.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answer to your question is yes, you can proxy through tor. I've done it in the past, issues you will face:

1. You'll have to run tor somewhere else if your running on heroku
2. Tor is pretty slow for scraping
3. You'll need to setup a proxy that can speak to tor (privoxy)
4. For any serious scraping you'll need to have multiple tors running
5. Even your tor ips will get blocked after a while.

Makes you think if it's worth the hassle. You can pay for ip masking proxy services which might be an easier way to go.

Think link got me some of the way when I was looking into this: http://www.howtoforge.com/ultimate-security-proxy-with-tor

Comment: @samfu_1 if this helped would appreciate you transfer the bounty - before it expires ;)